# Make Mathematica wait before replacing?

Tags: evaluation, replacement, hold

How can I force Mathematica to completely evaluate a subexpression before using a replacement rule?

For example, consider the following definition (for the series of `n` correction factors in Stirling's formula):

```
stirlingSeries[n_] := 
Series[Exp[
Total[Table[(-1)^(k - 1)/k t^k h^(k/2 - 1), {k, 3, 
   2 n + 2}]]], {h, 0, n}] /. 
t^m_ -> If[Mod[m, 2] == 0, (m - 1)!!, 0]
```

What I want to tell Mathematica to do is replace powers of `t` at the end, as the very last step in calculating `stirlingSeries[n]`.  Instead, it replaces them first.  This changes the result of the calculation.

Comment: I don't think I see the problem.  What are you expecting instead?

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess what could be the problem: you could have defined `m` before executing the definition of `stirlingSeries` that you wrote in the question. In that case, the replacement rule `->` would have assigned the current value of `m`, instead of the delayed value. To illustrate what I think went wrong, here is the scenario:

```
m = 4

(* ==> 4 *)


stirlingSeries[n_] := 
 Series[Exp[
    Total[Table[(-1)^(k - 1)/k t^k h^(k/2 - 1), {k, 3, 
       2 n + 2}]]], {h, 0, n}] /. 
  t^m_ -> If[Mod[m, 2] == 0, (m - 1)!!, 0]

stirlingSeries[4]
```

> $$1+\sqrt{h}-\frac{7 h}{12}+\frac{199
>    h^{3/2}}{540}-\frac{3193
>    h^2}{12960}+\frac{46801
>    h^{5/2}}{272160}-\frac{6084467
>    h^3}{48988800}+\frac{13558333
>    h^{7/2}}{146966400}-\frac{494880067
>    h^4}{7054387200}+O\left(h^{9/2}\right)$$

```
stirlingSeries[n_] := 
 Series[Exp[
    Total[Table[(-1)^(k - 1)/k t^k h^(k/2 - 1), {k, 3, 
       2 n + 2}]]], {h, 0, n}] /. 
  t^m_ :> If[Mod[m, 2] == 0, (m - 1)!!, 0]

stirlingSeries[4]
```

> $$1+\frac{h}{12}+\frac{h^2}{288}-\frac{139 h^3}{51840}-\frac{571
>    h^4}{2488320}+O\left(h^{9/2}\right)$$

On the last lines, I changed the definition to `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) which does what I believe you want: take the value of `m` to be that found in the pattern `t^m_`.